# Cant change background image in css on hover

Tags: html, css, background, hover

I have 6 `col-lg-3` in my container. Each `div` including another `div`, `h4` and `p`.
Included divs have `background-image`, and some properties in CSS.
And I want to change included div `background-image` on hovering `col-lg-3` div
But it just ignore `:hover` and nothing happening.

Ive tried not only change `background-images`, but change `color`, add `borders`, etc. But no response. Heres one of `div.col-lg-3`...

```css
.reasons .col-lg-3 div {
  width: 99px;
  height: 99px;
  margin: 10px auto 5px auto;
  background-size: 99px 99px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.community:hover div {
  background-image: url('img/communityReverse.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 community">
  <div style="background-image: url('img/community.png')"></div>
  <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

`.community:hover div{ ... }` seems not working, but for example `.community:hover h4{ font-size: 30px; }` ok, no problem. I cant see what is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an issue on your CSS, because you were trying to nest the div inside a class that wasn't declared before (`.reasons`). Aside from that, you should declare the `.community` class inside the nested div, so the image will be separated on the code (better view and easier to deal with), then, just make the `:hover` event apply to the class, so whenever the mouse enters the area, it'll trigger the event and change the background.

Here goes a Snippet for better view of the code and how it works :

```css
.community div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 99px;
  margin: 10px auto 5px auto;
  background-image: url("http://www.f-covers.com/cover/cute-baby-kitten-facebook-cover-timeline-banner-for-fb.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.community:hover div {
  background-image: url("https://www.freewebheaders.com/wordpress/wp-content/gallery/cats/lovely-american-shorthair-kitten-website-header.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 community">
  <div></div>
  <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

By the way, you don't have to specify a nested class when just wanting to work with general styles, as `.community` is nested as sibling with `.col-lg-3`, you can use either to change inner styles as I did in the Snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

you check this code you are working with wrong code

```
.community div:hover 
 {
    background-image: url('img/communityReverse.png');
 }
```

Comment: I need change bg exactly on hovering div.community block

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `!important` in your code otherwise you have done well

```css
.reasons .col-lg-3 div {
  width: 99px;
  height: 99px;
  margin: 10px auto 5px auto;
  background-size: 99px 99px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.community:hover div {
  background-image: url('img/communityReverse.png') !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 community">
  <div style="background-image: url('img/community.png')"></div>
  <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried !important ?

```
.community:hover div {
  background-image: url('img/communityReverse.png')!important;
}
```